# How to de-serialize XMLGregorianCalender with Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, xmlgregoriancalendar

When processing a `Json` string with `XMLGregorianCalender` using `Gson` I get the exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar() with no args

The object which is de-serialized by `fromJson(..)` with `Gson` has a `XMLGregorianCalender` object.

What can be the possible solution for the above error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract class `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` can not be a instantiated by its default/no-args constructor which makes `GSON` to fail.

If you resolve the class that extends above mentioned and that class has a public no-args constructor you can de-serialize that directly. For example, in my case:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGC = gson.fromJson(strXMLGC,
        com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal
            .jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.class);
```

**A generic way** to get it working everywhere - without caring the implementing class - is to define a custom `JsonDeserializer`. To make de-serialing easy you could first create an adapter class that holds the data that `XMLGregorianCalendar`'s `JSON` has:

```
@Getter
public class XMLGregoriancalendarAdapterClass {
    private BigInteger year;
    private int month, day, timezone,  hour, minute, second;
    private BigDecimal fractionalSecond;        
}
```

Data types of each field in above class are chosen to match one specific method for constructing `XMLGregorianCalendar` with `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory`.

Having above adapter class create a de-serialiazer like:

```
public class XMLGregorianCalendarDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<XMLGregorianCalendar> {
    @Override
    public XMLGregorianCalendar deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // Easily parse the adapter class first
        XMLGregoriancalendarAdapterClass ac = 
                new Gson().fromJson(json, 
                        XMLGregoriancalendarAdapterClass.class);
        try {
            // Then return a new newXMLGregorianCalendar
            // using values in adapter class
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(ac.getYear(), ac.getMonth(), 
                            ac.getDay(), ac.getHour(),        
                            ac.getMinute(), ac.getSecond(),
                            ac.getFractionalSecond(), ac.getTimezone());
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using above you can construct `GSON` like:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(
                     XMLGregorianCalendar.class,
                     new XMLGregorianCalendarDeserializer() )
                .create();
```

after which it is just:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGC2 = 
        gson.fromJson(json, YourClassHavingXMLGregorianCalendar.class);
```

Comment: Thanks @pirho it is working after the deserialiser adding !!!! Thanks !!!!